# Cannot Access Boot Option Screen When Dual-Booting Ubuntu 11 With Windows 7

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation

I installed Windows 7 a couple months ago on one 500GB hard drive, just 30 minutes ago I chose to install Ubuntu 11 and Dual Boot it with Windows 7, but now, when I turn on my computer my screen says "Input Not Supported", I wait a few minutes and it goes straight to Ubuntu. I don't even get the boot option screen or anything.

I need a fix and need as much help as possible. Will be willing to pay for someone to help me quick. I own a business and all of my documents, etc. are on my Windows 7 Operating System.

Answer (score 2):

Log into Ubuntu and re-install Grub `sudo update-grub`. Hopefully that will find the correct partitions. If it didn't reinstall Grub to your main hard disk.